# Wrong image from

Tags: android, android-adapter

I have `GridView` with images from `drawable`. When I click any image it opens always 1st element from array, not certain clicked element. Whats wrong with my code? Have you any ideas? Thank you!
What happened when I click any image:

```
  private GridView.OnItemClickListener gridviewOnItemClickListener = new GridView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                FullImageActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("id", position);
        startActivity(i);       
    }
};
```

> There is my FullImageActivity

```
public class FullImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    SlideImageAdapter adapter;
    MainActivity mainActivity;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_image);
       getMyIntent();   
    }

    private void getMyIntent(){       
        Intent intent = getIntent();   
        int position = intent.getExtras().getInt("id");
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myViewPager);
        adapter = new SlideImageAdapter(this, position);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

> There is my SlideImageAdapter

```
public class SlideImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    int number;

    public SlideImageAdapter(Context mContext, int number){

        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return MainActivity.mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view==(LinearLayout)object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {


        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View item_view =  layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout, container, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);

            imageView.setImageResource(MainActivity.mThumbIds[position]);

        container.addView(item_view);


        return item_view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

        container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your code for click?

Comment: @surya edited..

Comment: Value for the image selected is passed to the adapter as a number ,where is this used ?

Comment: It appears that either the `"id"` extra is not present in the new activity or is being incorrectly added as an extra. You can distinguish these cases by calling the two-argument version of `getInt` inside `getMyIntent()`. Try `int position = intent.getExtras().getInt("id", -1);` and check whether the position is 0 or -1. (By the way, you could also use `intent.getIntExtra("id", -1)`.)

Comment: @surya yes, I tried do this. If I change value of `position`(method `instantiateItem`) to value of `number` then opens correct image, but if I try swipe left or right it will never change image.

Comment: You need to use position and based left swipe or right u need to use position +1 or position-1

Comment: @surya But if I dont use number, swipe works correct.. Could you show example code what u mean?

Comment: Item selected is at position your image array should index based on this value not on the poision ,cause position always starts from 0 and goes till end of list but in your case you should start from number and array should be accesses based on that

Comment: If I understand you, I should use number like a position but if i want swipe to another image, I must write additional methods, right?

Comment: You have 10 images in the array,selected position is 4 .when u show u show imagearray[4].but now you swipe  left the value returned should be imagearray[3] and when u swipe right value should imagearray[5].please check whats happening in the logic in your code and you will have clarity

Comment: if any answer helps you, you should mark it as correct.

Comment: @SarthakMittal yep, sorry. Your answers works. I played with LogCat to understand logic of this adapter :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call:

```
 viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
```

after:

```
 viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

you are fetching the position, and sending it to the adapter, but you are not using it. once the adapter is set, you can manually set the position.